# What is the most helpful dictionary for post-medieval works of philosophy and mathematics?

Tags: resource-request, mathematics, dictionary, philosophy

I need Latin for my natural-language artificial intelligence research, and I've been at it for enough years that I can read Latin well, but need extensive practice with composition. Thus I have decided to translate (or maybe I should say "work on translating for a few years") Wittgenstein's Tractatus Logico-Philosophicus. I'm sure there must be standard translations for the philosophical and mathematical terms that might show up in, say, Descartes, or in doctoral theses by, say, 19th century mathematicians or philosophers. My Oxford Desk dictionary, and some other small ones I have, are way too concise, and "Smith's Copious and Critical English-Latin Dictionary" does not include even the most basic mathematical terms like derivative or integral (both are nouns), limit, or matrix. Wiktionary is similar. I can handle German-Latin dictionaries if one exists, or even French-Latin, if perhaps there IS a good dictionary but it's not in English.

Gratias tibi ago.